# Why does Kestrel fail to start when certificates are present?

Tags: windows, apache, asp.net-core, ssl-certificate, kestrel

I have Apache 2.4 as a reverse proxy with Kestrel on Windows Server 2019. I have one app already running on the server. I set up a second app with its own `appname.conf` file in `C:\Apache24\conf\sites-enabled` and added new, unexpired SSL certificate files to `C:\Apache24\conf\ssl\appname`.

In the app's `Program.cs`, this is the `CreateHostBuilder`, where I've specified the ports to be used so they are different from the first app's:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseUrls("http://localhost:5002", "https://localhost:5003");
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

When running the command to start the app on the server (`dotnet appname.dll`), I get this error:

> crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
>         Unable to start Kestrel.
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.
>
> To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.
>   For more information on configuring HTTPS see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848054.

Even though I have the real SSL certificates, I've run `dotnet dev-certs https --trust`, as the error suggests, even going as far as deleting the certs from the Windows cert manager GUI first, as suggested [on Github](https://github.com/aspnet/DotNetTools/issues/464#issuecomment-430327197), to no avail.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1) As Kestrel runs behind Apache, you don't really need the HTTPS URL. 2) If you insist HTTPS, then you must have a valid certificate mapping created in Windows HTTP API for port 5003. More can be learned from https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments by Lex Li, `UseUrls()` doesn't need an `https` version of the URL. To have additional apps on the same server, only an unused port needs to be provided to Kestrel, and this is how it's done. Here is how `CreateHostBuilder` should look:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseUrls("http://localhost:5002");
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```